# index 398120 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 398120

Tags: filtering, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to filter a numpy array with the code below. but I get this error: index 398120 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 398120, how can I solve it?

```
for n in range(m):
if n == 0:
    t1dc[n]=t1[n]
    t2dc[n]=t2[n]
    t3dc[n]=t3[n]
else:
    t1dc[n]=0.0158*t1[n]+0.9843*t1dc[n-1]
    t2dc[n]=0.0158*t2[n]+0.9843*t2dc[n-1]
    t3dc[n]=0.0158*t3[n]+0.9843*t3dc[n-1]
```

Comment: `n-1` is larger than the size of array for one or more of the arrays. Please provide a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example